# Single-character switches in block [-abc] with parameters

Tags: bash, shell-script

Imagine you have a command `foo` that takes three single-character switches `a`, `b`, and `c`. All of these switches take any number of options.

i.e. `foo -a opt1 -b opt2 -c opt3`

What happens (or what should happen) when the switches are in a single block?

i.e. `foo -abc opt1 opt2 opt3`

Is there a standard practice for what happens (i.e. `c` gets `opt1 opt2 opt3`, or `a` gets `bc opt1 opt2 opt3`, or an error gets throw, etc,.) or is it up to the program interpreting it?

Comment: The "combined" form (second case) should only be used for switches that do not take parameters.

Comment: `foo -abc opt1 opt2 opt3` is confusing - could be interpreted as `-a` with arguments `bc  opt1 opt2 opt3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The POSIX standard says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html):

> **Guideline 5:** One or more options without option-arguments, followed by at most one option that takes an option-argument, should be accepted when grouped behind one '-' delimiter.

So, in a POSIX-compliant utility, `foo -abc opt1 opt2 opt3` means:

- `-a` option with `bc` as option-argument.
- `opt1`, `opt2` and `opt3` as standard arguments.

If `foo` is not a POSIX-compliant utility, then its manual should clarify those situations.

Comment: Huh. Does that mean if 'a' and 'b' don't take arguments, it would be `-a`, `-b`, and `-c opt1`?

Comment: @MynockSpit Yes, and it can even be write as `-abcopt1`. See the examples section of [`getopt()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html).

Comment: But then there's Guideline 6 that says "Each option and option-argument should be a separate argument" and point 2 in Utility argument syntax states that "a conforming application shall use separate arguments for that option and its option-argument", so if `-a` takes a mandatory argument, it should be given as `-a bc`, not as `-abc`. But it also seems to state that `-abc` should be parsed in the same way in any case.

Comment: @ilkkachu I think that's a matter of [POSIX terminology](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap01.html#tag_01_05). I mean, POSIX states that `-a opt` syntax shall be accepted but it does not explicitly state that `-aopt` is not a valid alternative. And `getopt()` itself provides that alternative behavior anyway.

Comment: @nxnev, well, it says "shall" on both counts, so it's mandatory to both give the argument separately, and to accept it in the same argument. Probably a case of "be strict in what you provide, but lenient in what you accept". Or totally illogical, depending on how you look at it...

Answer (score 3):

In programs using `getopt()`, if `-a` takes an argument, then `foo -abc opt1 opt2 opt3` is `-a` with the argument `bc`, then the non-options `opt1`, `opt2`, `opt3`. If `-a` doesn't take an argument then the behaviour depends on if `-b` and `-c` take arguments.

The [POSIX description of `getopt()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) is rather clear on this:

> If the option takes an argument, *getopt*() shall set the variable *optarg* to point to the option-argument as follows:
>
> 1. If the option was the last character in the string pointed to by an element of *argv*, then *optarg* shall contain the next element of *argv*, ...
> 2. Otherwise, *optarg* shall point to the string following the option character in that element of *argv* ...

But that's not to say there might not be programs that do things differently. The traditional way of passing arguments to `tar` puts all the flags in a bundle in the first command line argument, with all required arguments to the options in the following command line arguments, in order.

In this example from the [FreeBSD tar manual](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?tar(1)):

```
tar tbf 32 file.tar
```

the `b` and `f` flags take arguments, which are `32` and `file.tar`, here. Of course this mode is rather distinct in that the arguments are *not* preceded by a dash. Using a dash
leads to more `getopt`-like parsing, which means that `tar xfv` and `tar -xfv` are different (since `-f` takes an argument).

Then, of course, some programs take options that are full words, but still start with a single dash, so without knowing the program in question, there's no way to tell if `-abc` is one option, three options, or one option with an argument. The GNU style of prefixing long options with a double dash at least makes the distinction clear.

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on the program interpreting your input.

Typically, you can chain short options together (e.g. `foo -abc`) as long as those options take no arguments.  This is both by convention and because standard argument parsing libraries (such as getopts) support this.

However, I'm not aware of any commonly-used programs off the top of my head that do not support chaining short options.